# Linear map of approximation

Tags: approximation

I need to answer this question, but I don't even clearly understand what is wanted: for approximation problem on $[a,b]$ show a linear map $x \rightarrow t$ that shows it is equivalent to same approximation problem on interval $[-1,1]$ or $[0,1]$ and show how both the function and norm change. Thanks.

Comment: There is not enough information to understand what the problem is.

Comment: @copper.hat Unfortunately, that's the entire text of the problem, and it is unclear to me what is expected. That's why I posted here, assuming there is some reading between the lines skill I don't have yet.

Comment: Sorry, nothing rings a bell for me.